# how to find out what process(es) caused the autogrowth of a database or a database file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, tempdb, process

I have a process(es) hungry for tempdb, but I am struggling to identify this process.

any ways I could achieve this?

> We have been alerted as Tempdb has now grown into the space you
>   reclaimed on the T:\ drive earlier. Again, there is 10MB remaining on
>   disk. I can see a number of auto growth events across the data files
>   on the REP instance starting at 10:18AM this morning. In total there
>   were 330 auto growth events at 512MB each, totalling 168GB.
>
> It is difficult to highlight after the fact what has used this space
>   in Tempdb, are you aware of any processes that may be using Tempdb in
>   this manner today?

/*------------------------------------------------------------*\

**Identifying How Often an Auto-growth Event has Occurred**

When SQL Server performs an auto-grow event, the transaction that triggered the auto-grow event will have to wait until the auto-grow event completes before the transaction can finish. These auto-growth events cause your performance to degrade a little when an auto-grow event is taking place. For this reason it is best if you can size your database appropriately so auto-growth events rarely occur.

If you are interested in how often an auto-growth event occurs on your system you can capture those events using a trace. By knowing which databases are performing auto-growth events allows you to adjust those database file growth properties so they will perform auto-growth events less frequently. You can use the profiler “Data File Auto-grow” and/or the “Log File Auto-grow” events to track these database auto-growth events. If you are running SQL Server 2005 or above, both these auto-grow events are already being captured by the default trace. If you haven’t turned off the default trace then you can use the default trace file to find these auto-grow events. If you have turned off the default trace you can either enable it, or setup a new profiler trace to capture the “Data File Auto-grow” and “Log File Auto-grow” events.

The default trace logs to a file. I have provided the code in Listing 4 to show you how to extract all the auto-growth events from the default trace files. If you create your own profiler trace session to capture these auto-grow events then you will need to modify this script to meet your profiler trace settings.

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-database-growth-and-autogrowth-settings/

marcelo miorelli
11-mar-2014

```
\*--------------------------------------------------*/
DECLARE @filename NVARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @bc INT;
DECLARE @ec INT;
DECLARE @bfn VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @efn VARCHAR(10);

-- Get the name of the current default trace
SELECT @filename = CAST(value AS NVARCHAR(1000))
FROM ::fn_trace_getinfo(DEFAULT)
WHERE traceid = 1 AND property = 2;

-- rip apart file name into pieces
SET @filename = REVERSE(@filename);
SET @bc = CHARINDEX('.',@filename);
SET @ec = CHARINDEX('_',@filename)+1;
SET @efn = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@filename,1,@bc));
SET @bfn = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@filename,@ec,LEN(@filename)));

-- set filename without rollover number
SET @filename = @bfn + @efn

-- process all trace files
SELECT 
  ftg.StartTime
,te.name AS EventName
,DB_NAME(ftg.databaseid) AS DatabaseName  
,ftg.Filename
,(ftg.IntegerData*8)/1024.0 AS GrowthMB 
,(ftg.duration/1000)AS DurMS
FROM ::fn_trace_gettable(@filename, DEFAULT) AS ftg 
INNER JOIN sys.trace_events AS te ON ftg.EventClass = te.trace_event_id  
WHERE (ftg.EventClass = 92  -- Date File Auto-grow
    OR ftg.EventClass = 93) -- Log File Auto-grow
ORDER BY ftg.StartTime
```

Comment: Possible Duplication: See the accepted answer here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13911/how-to-find-the-sql-statements-that-caused-tempdb-growth

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT well spotted, however this question is related to a process that has caused the autogrowth, maybe the process is still running, maybe it has finished

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to find out what process caused the autogrowth is to use Extended events esp. `EVENT` --> `sqlserver.database_file_size_change` & `sqlserver.databases_log_file_size_changed` and `ACTION` --> `sqlserver.sql_text`.

Looks like [@DBA_ANDY already did the hard work of writing an XEvent](http://nebraskasql.blogspot.com/2016/06/finding-file-growths-with-extended.html)

```
-- Original Author : @DBA_ANDY http://nebraskasql.blogspot.com/2016/06/finding-file-growths-with-extended.html
-- Modified by : Kin to filter on tempdb autogrowth events
SET NOCOUNT ON 
/* Create Extended Events Session */
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM master.sys.server_event_sessions WHERE name = 'DemoFileSize')
 DROP EVENT SESSION [DemoFileSize] ON SERVER
GO
CREATE EVENT SESSION [DemoFileSize] ON SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.database_file_size_change(SET collect_database_name=(1)
    ACTION(package0.collect_system_time,sqlos.task_time,
 sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,
 sqlserver.client_pid,sqlserver.database_id,sqlserver.database_name,
 sqlserver.server_instance_name,sqlserver.session_id,
 sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.username)
 WHERE ( [database_id] = ( 2 ) -- This is tempdb database id
),
 /* Note -  predicate/filter - will collect only for tempdb */
ADD EVENT sqlserver.databases_log_file_size_changed(
    ACTION(package0.collect_system_time,sqlos.task_time,
 sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,
 sqlserver.client_pid,sqlserver.database_id,sqlserver.database_name,
 sqlserver.server_instance_name,sqlserver.session_id,
 sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.username)
 WHERE ( [database_id] = ( 2 ) -- This is tempdb database id
  )
 /* Note -  predicate/filter - will collect only for tempdb */
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'D:\XEvent_logs\DemoFileSize.xel',-- change HERE !!
 max_file_size=(500),max_rollover_files=(10))
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,
 MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,
 MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=ON)
GO

ALTER EVENT SESSION [DemoFileSize] ON SERVER
STATE = START;
GO
```

shred the XEvent xml ...

```
SELECT
Case when file_type = 'Data file' Then 'Data File Grow' Else File_Type End AS [Event Name]
, database_name AS DatabaseName
, dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, sysutcdatetime(), sysdatetime()), timestamp1) as LocalTimeStamp
/* added the timestamp and in XE is UTC - this code converts it to local server time zone */
, file_names
, size_change_mb
, duration
, client_app_name AS Client_Application
, client_hostname
, session_id AS SessionID
, sql_txt   ----------------> This is the process TSQL text !
, sql_username
, Is_Automatic

FROM
(
SELECT
(n.value ('(data[@name="size_change_kb"]/value)[1]', 'int')/1024.0) AS size_change_mb
, n.value('(@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime2') as timestamp1
, n.value ('(data[@name="database_name"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS database_name
, n.value ('(data[@name="duration"]/value)[1]', 'int') AS duration
, n.value ('(data[@name="file_type"]/text)[1]','nvarchar(50)') AS file_type
, n.value ('(action[@name="client_app_name"]/value)[1]','nvarchar(50)') AS client_app_name
, n.value ('(action[@name="session_id"]/value)[1]','nvarchar(50)') AS session_id
, n.value ('(action[@name="client_hostname"]/value)[1]','nvarchar(50)') AS Client_HostName
, n.value ('(data[@name="file_name"]/value)[1]','nvarchar(50)') AS file_names
, n.value ('(data[@name="is_automatic"]/value)[1]','nvarchar(50)') AS Is_Automatic
, n.value ('(action[@name="sql_text"]/value)[1]','nvarchar(500)') AS sql_txt
, n.value ('(action[@name="username"]/value)[1]','nvarchar(50)') AS sql_username

FROM
(
SELECT CAST(event_data AS XML) AS event_data
FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file(
N'D:\XEvent_logs\DemoFileSize*.xel' -- CHANGE HERE !!
, NULL
, NULL
, NULL
)
) AS Event_Data_Table
CROSS APPLY event_data.nodes('event') AS q(n)) xyz
ORDER BY timestamp1 desc
```

Below is the output:

[image]
Important things :

- You can use [my modified script](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/82633/8783) for reporting on autogrowth events.
- [Properly size your data and log files](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46686/8783), so that autogrowth events do not occur on a frequent basis. Autogrowth should be as an emergency helper !
- Enable Instant file initialization, so that data file autogrowth events can be fast.
- Use predicates in XEvent e.g. on certain important databases or on the `size_change_mb` to log only events that meet those predicates.
- Use sensible target file size e.g. shredding a 1GB XML will cause you more trouble than shredding a 50 MB XML.
- Refer to [This is how to shred Extended Event XML faster](https://www.codykonior.com/2015/10/18/this-is-how-to-shred-extended-event-xml-faster/) or [How can I shred this Extended Events XML as fast as possible?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/121495/8783)