# Does SQL Server Only Perform Calculations In A SELECT List Once?

Tags: sql-server, view, computed-column

Take the following example:

```
SELECT <CalculationA> As ColA,
       <CalculationB> As ColB,
       <CalculationA> + <CalculationB> As ColC
FROM TableA
```

Would CalculationA and CalculationB, each be calculated twice?
Or would the optimizer be clever enough to calculate them once and use the result twice?

I would like to perform a test to see the result for myself, however, I am not sure how I could check something like this.

My assumption is that it would perform the calculation twice.
In which case, depending upon the calculations involved, might it be better to use a derived table, or nested view? Consider the following:

```
SELECT TableB.ColA,
       TableB.ColB,
       TableB.ColA + TableB.ColB AS ColC,
FROM(    
      SELECT <CalculationA> As ColA,
             <CalculationB> As ColB
      FROM TableA
    ) As TableB
```

In this case, I would hope that the calculations would only be performed once?

Please can someone confirm or refute my assumptions?
Or instruct me on how to test something like this for myself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Most of the information you will need is going to be in the execution plan ( and the plan XML).

Take this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(val) As ColA,
       COUNT(val2) As ColB,
       COUNT(val) +  COUNT(val2) As ColC
FROM dbo.TableA;
```

The execution plan  *(opened with [sentryone plan explorer](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer))* shows what steps it went through:

[image]

With the stream aggregate aggregating the values for **EXPR1005** & **EXPR1006**

[image]

If we want to know what these are, we could get the exact info on these expressions from the query plan XML:

```
<ColumnReference Column="Expr1005" />
<ScalarOperator ScalarString="COUNT([Database].[dbo].[TableA].[val])">
<Aggregate AggType="COUNT_BIG" Distinct="false">
```

With the first compute scalar computing `ColA & ColB`:

[image]

And the last compute scalar being a simple addition:

[image]

This is reading it as the data flows, in theory you should be reading it from left to right if going over the logical execution.

In that case, `EXPR1004`  is calling the other expressions, `EXPR1002` & `EXPR1003`. In turn these are calling `EXPR1005` & `EXPR1006`.

> Would CalculationA and CalculationB, each be calculated twice? Or
>   would the optimizer be clever enough to calculate them once and use
>   the result twice?

Previous tests show that in this case `ColC` is simplified as an addition of the calculations that are defined as `ColA` & `ColB`.

As a result, `ColA` & `ColB` are only calculated once.

---

**Grouping by 200 distinct values**

If we are grouping by 200 distinct values (val3) the same is shown:

```
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;
SELECT SUM(val) As ColA,
       SUM(val2) As ColB,
       SUM(val) +  SUM(val2) As ColC
FROM dbo.TableA
GROUP BY val3;
```

Aggregating down to these 200 distinct values in `val3`

[image]

performing the sums on val & val2 and then adding them together for ColC:

[image]

Even if we are grouping on all but one non-unique value, the same addition should be seen for the compute scalar.

---

**Adding a function to  ColA & ColB**

Even if we change the query to this:

```
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;
SELECT ABS(SUM(val)) As ColA,
       ABS(SUM(val2)) As ColB,
       SUM(val) +  SUM(val2) As ColC
FROM dbo.TableA
```

The aggregations are still not going to be calculated twice, we are simply adding the `ABS()` function to the resultset of the aggregation, wich is one row:

[image]

[image]

Ofcourse, running `SUM(ABS(ColA)` & `SUM(ABS(ColB))` will make the optimizer unable to use the same expression for calculating `ColC`.

---

If you want to go deeper in when this happens I would nudge you towards [Query Optimizer Deep Dive - Part 1](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/04/query-optimizer-deep-dive-part-1.html) (until Part 4) by Paul White.

Anther way to dive deeper into query execution phases is by adding these hints:

```
OPTION 
(
    RECOMPILE, 
    QUERYTRACEON 3604,
    QUERYTRACEON 8605
);
```

This will expose the input tree as created by the optimizer.

The adding of the two previous calculated values to get `ColC` is then translated to:

```
AncOp_PrjEl COL: Expr1004 

ScaOp_Arithmetic x_aopAdd

    ScaOp_Identifier COL: Expr1002 

    ScaOp_Identifier COL: Expr1003
```

This information is already present in the **Input Tree**, even before the simplification phase has taken place, showing that the optimizer immediately knows that it does not have to perform the same calculation twice.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. It is going to take me some time to digest, as most of it is way over my head. However, it has given me several areas of further research. If I understand correctly, in summary, the optimizer will do it's best to only perform the calculations once, except where it cannot guarantee that the calculations are the same.

Comment: @Gravitate that about sums it up! Sorry I tend to put too much unneeded stuff in there, happy to help :).

Comment: No, there's nothing unneeded, I just wanted to be sure that I had understood the conclusion before I dug into the detail. Thanks again.

Comment: Having the same Expression label doesn't guarantee that the underlying calculation is only done once. See this answer for some discussion on this https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/30947/3690

Answer (score 5):

If the first part of your calculation is an actual calculation (`Col1 + Col2`) and not a function, then the individual calculations are performed for each "calculation" step.

> ```
> SELECT <CalculationA> As ColA,
>        <CalculationB> As ColB,
>        <CalculationA> + <CalculationB> As ColC
> FROM TableA
> ```

If we replace `<CalculationA>` from your statement with a valid calculation using `ColA` and `ColB` from a table, and repeat this for each subsequent `<CalculationB>,...` step, then the actual task of calculating the result will be performed for each step individually.

To reproduce my statement paste the following code snippets into SQL Server Management Studio and run. Make sure you have turned on the option **Include Actual Execution Plan**.

[image: Include Actual Execution Plan]

It creates a database, a table, populates the table and performs a calculation which produces an execution plan.

```
CREATE DATABASE Q252661
GO
USE Q252661
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Q252661_TableA  (
    ColA  INT,
    ColB  INT,
    ColC  INT,
    ColD  INT)   

GO

INSERT INTO Q252661_TableA
(
    ColA,
    ColB,
    ColC,
    ColD
)
VALUES
(
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
),(
    2,
    4,
    8,
    16
)

GO
SELECT  ColA + ColB AS ColA, 
        ColC + ColD AS ColB,
        ColA + ColB + ColC + ColD AS ColC
FROM    Q252661_TableA

GO
```

The query will run and produce a graphical execution plan similar to the following:

[image: Graphical Execution Plan of ADDing values]
**<sup>Graphical Execution Plan of ADDing values</sup>**

As in Randi's answer we'll focus on the **Compute Scalar** operator.

If you click on the Query Execution Plan in SSMS and right-click to show the actual plan:

[image: Show Execution Plan XML...]

.. you will find the following XML (focusing on the **Compute Scalar** portion):

```
          <ComputeScalar>
            <DefinedValues>
              <DefinedValue>
                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1003" />
                <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[Q252661].[dbo].[Q252661_TableA].[ColA]+[Q252661].[dbo].[Q252661_TableA].[ColB]">
                  <Arithmetic Operation="ADD">
                    <ScalarOperator>
                      <Identifier>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[Q252661]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Q252661_TableA]" Column="ColA" />
                      </Identifier>
                    </ScalarOperator>
                    <ScalarOperator>
                      <Identifier>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[Q252661]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Q252661_TableA]" Column="ColB" />
                      </Identifier>
                    </ScalarOperator>
                  </Arithmetic>
                </ScalarOperator>
              </DefinedValue>
              <DefinedValue>
                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1004" />
                <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[Q252661].[dbo].[Q252661_TableA].[ColC]+[Q252661].[dbo].[Q252661_TableA].[ColD]">
                  <Arithmetic Operation="ADD">
                    <ScalarOperator>
                      <Identifier>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[Q252661]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Q252661_TableA]" Column="ColC" />
                      </Identifier>
                    </ScalarOperator>
                    <ScalarOperator>
                      <Identifier>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[Q252661]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Q252661_TableA]" Column="ColD" />
                      </Identifier>
                    </ScalarOperator>
                  </Arithmetic>
                </ScalarOperator>
              </DefinedValue>
              <DefinedValue>
                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1005" />
                <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[Q252661].[dbo].[Q252661_TableA].[ColA]+[Q252661].[dbo].[Q252661_TableA].[ColB]+[Q252661].[dbo].[Q252661_TableA].[ColC]+[Q252661].[dbo].[Q252661_TableA].[ColD]">
                  <Arithmetic Operation="ADD">
                    <ScalarOperator>
                      <Arithmetic Operation="ADD">
                        <ScalarOperator>
                          <Arithmetic Operation="ADD">
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[Q252661]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Q252661_TableA]" Column="ColA" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[Q252661]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Q252661_TableA]" Column="ColB" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Arithmetic>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                        <ScalarOperator>
                          <Identifier>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[Q252661]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Q252661_TableA]" Column="ColC" />
                          </Identifier>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </Arithmetic>
                    </ScalarOperator>
                    <ScalarOperator>
                      <Identifier>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[Q252661]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Q252661_TableA]" Column="ColD" />
                      </Identifier>
                    </ScalarOperator>
                  </Arithmetic>
                </ScalarOperator>
              </DefinedValue>
            </DefinedValues>
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="23" EstimateCPU="8.07E-05" EstimateIO="0.0032035" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="2" LogicalOp="Table Scan" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Table Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032842" TableCardinality="2">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[Q252661]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Q252661_TableA]" Column="ColA" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[Q252661]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Q252661_TableA]" Column="ColB" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[Q252661]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Q252661_TableA]" Column="ColC" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[Q252661]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Q252661_TableA]" Column="ColD" />
              </OutputList>
              <TableScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                <DefinedValues>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Q252661]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Q252661_TableA]" Column="ColA" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Q252661]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Q252661_TableA]" Column="ColB" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Q252661]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Q252661_TableA]" Column="ColC" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Q252661]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Q252661_TableA]" Column="ColD" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                </DefinedValues>
                <Object Database="[Q252661]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Q252661_TableA]" IndexKind="Heap" Storage="RowStore" />
              </TableScan>
            </RelOp>
          </ComputeScalar>
```

So each individual calculation is performed again and again in the case of the values being retrieved from an actual table. The following XML fragment is from the above summary:

```
                <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[Q252661].[dbo].[Q252661_TableA].[ColA]+[Q252661].[dbo].[Q252661_TableA].[ColB]">
                  <Arithmetic Operation="ADD">
```

There are five `<Arithmetic Operation="ADD">` steps in the execution plan.

---

### Answering your Question

> Would CalculationA and CalculationB, each be calculated twice?

Yes, if the calculations are actual sums of columns as per the example. The last calculation would be the sum of `CalculationA + CalculationB`.

> Or would the optimizer be clever enough to calculate them once and use the result twice?

It depends on what you are calculating. 
- In this example: yes. 
- In Randi's answer: no.

> My assumption is that it would perform the calculation twice.

You are right for certain calculations.

> In which case, depending upon the calculations involved, might it be better to use a derived table, or nested view?

Correct.

---

Once you have finished you can drop your database again:

```
USE [master]
GO
DROP DATABASE Q252661
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Your answer seems to be a bit more pessimistic than @Randi's, about how complex the calculations can be before the optimizer has to start calculating them multiple times?

Comment: Nothing to do with being pessimistic. It's just facts. Your question and subsequent answers depend on the "Calculation" you are performing and probably a lot of unknown factors. You will have to try it out for the calculations you are expecting to encounter during the development and/or DBA activities.

Comment: You can describe facts in an optimistic or pessimistic way. I understand it depends upon the exact calculations. My comment was merely pointing out that @Randi's answer suggests that the optimizer is better at reusing calculations than yours seems to. I know that it would be best to try it out for myself on the specific calculations, but as I said in my question, prior to receiving your answers, I didn't know how to check if the calculations are being reused. So, thank you. You have both given me plenty of avenues of further research.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are already good answers to the question I will focus on the DRY-aspect (DRY = don't repeat yourself).

I got used to use `CROSS APPLY`, if I have to do the same calculations in the same query multiple times (don't forget `GROUP BY / WHERE / ORDER BY`, where the same calcualtions tend to occure again and again and again).

```
SELECT calc.ColA,
       calc.ColB,
       calc.ColA + calc.ColB AS ColC
  FROM TableA AS a
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT a.Org_A * 100 AS ColA
                   , a.Org_B / 100 AS ColB
             ) AS calc
 WHERE calc.ColB = @whatever
 ORDER BY calc.ColA
```

When one calculation depends on another, there is no reason to not use multiple `CROSS APPLY` calls to calculate interim results (same, when you need to use the end result in the `WHERE` / `ORDER BY`)

```
SELECT calc1.ColA,
       calc2.ColB,
       calc3.ColC
  FROM TableA AS a
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT a.Org_A    * 100        AS ColA) AS calc1
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT calc1.ColA * 100        AS ColB) AS calc2
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT calc1.ColA + calc2.ColB AS ColC) AS calc3
 WHERE calc.ColB = @whatever
 ORDER BY calc.ColA, calc3.ColC
```

The main point for doing this is that you have to modfiy / correct only one row of code when you find a bug or have to change something instead of multiple occurences and do not risk to have multiple (slightly different, since you forgot to change one) versions of the same calculation.

PS: regarding the readability `CROSS APPLY` will usually win vs. several nested sub selects (or CTEs), particularly when the calculations use columns from different source tables or you have interim results.

Answer (score -2):

If both Expressions are deterministic, the optimizer will reuse the previously calculated results and simply add them. If either expression is nondeterministic, that expression MUST be recalculated.

Comment: It would be nice to see some evidence to support your assertions. You can edit the question to add it.