# Cannot run query to get deadlock graph in a timely fashion

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I am trying to get deadlock information from a sql-server by using this query

```
select XEventData.XEvent.value('(data/value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as DeadlockGraph
FROM
(select CAST(target_data as xml) as TargetData
from sys.dm_xe_session_targets st
join sys.dm_xe_sessions s on s.address = st.event_session_address
where name = 'system_health') AS Data
CROSS APPLY TargetData.nodes ('//RingBufferTarget/event') AS XEventData (XEvent)
where XEventData.XEvent.value('@name', 'varchar(4000)') = 'xml_deadlock_report'
```

The query however takes forever and returns an empty result.

Why does it take that long time and is the deadlock information you get from this views retroactive so I will be able to pinpoint a deadlock that occured some time ago?

Comment: Possibly relevant https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/30862/3690

Answer (score 10):

### Why Does It Take A Long Time?

You have to be quite careful when querying XML. Your query is a bit of a disaster in that regard, specifically this part: `where XEventData.XEvent.value('@name', 'varchar(4000)') = 'xml_deadlock_report'`

Which results in a whole bunch of XML being dragged around, joined, and much later filtered:

[image: NUTS]

You're much better off using the [exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/exist-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15) method like so:

```
SELECT
    DeadlockGraph = 
        XEventData.XEvent.value('(data/value)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
FROM
(
    SELECT
        TargetData = CONVERT(xml, st.target_data)
    FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets AS st
    JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions AS s
        ON s.address = st.event_session_address
    WHERE s.name = 'system_health'
) AS Data
CROSS APPLY TargetData.nodes('//RingBufferTarget/event') AS XEventData(XEvent)
WHERE XEventData.XEvent.exist('/event/@name[ .= "xml_deadlock_report"]') = 1;
```

The XML filtering is still a bit awkward, but it happens much earlier on in the execution plan.

You may also find it beneficial to drop the converted XML into a `#temp` table first, so that validation of the XML structure only needs to occur once.

```
SELECT
    TargetData = 
        CONVERT(xml, st.target_data)
INTO #x
FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets AS st
JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions AS s
    ON s.address = st.event_session_address
WHERE s.name = 'system_health';

SELECT
    DeadlockGraph = 
        XEventData.XEvent.value('(data/value)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
FROM
(
    SELECT
        TargetData
    FROM #x
) AS Data
CROSS APPLY TargetData.nodes('//RingBufferTarget/event') AS XEventData(XEvent)
WHERE XEventData.XEvent.exist('/event/@name[ .= "xml_deadlock_report"]') = 1;
```

If you'd like an alternative, you might find [sp_BlitzLock](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/12/introducing-sp_blitzlock-troubleshooting-sql-server-deadlocks/) useful.

### Are Views Retroactive?

Only by luck. There are limits to the size of the data, and if there are a lot of events logged they may push useful deadlock data out. You are able to edit the session, as [Aaron Betrand notes in this blog post](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6456/improve-sql-server-extended-events-systemhealth-session/).

If you are specifically interested in deadlocks, your best bet is to set up an extended event session dedicated to that.